# How to right-click drag with trackpad?

Tags: trackpad

To reiterate, this is not a regular drag but a *right-click drag*. Is it possible to do this with a mac trackpad? At the moment it is to pan in an online 3D tool, but it's not the first time and I never knew how to do this with the trackpad.

I have searched for other similar questions but no solution is working for me, although surprisingly this has only been asked a few times.

Edit: Bettertouchtool's (or other apps) workarounds are also welcome

Comment: Which online 3D tool?

Comment: @theonlygusti not sure that's relevant but it's this: https://item.engineering/ESes/tools/engineeringtool

Comment: Two finger drag works for me on that app.

Comment: Both of my answers work in that webapp in Safari and Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In System Preferences > Trackpad, set Secondary Click to 'Click in bottom right corner', and then click with one finger in the bottom right corner and use another finger (lightly placed without clicking) on the trackpad to move around.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works on newer Macbook Airs (M2) as right click disengages. Contacted Apple about it and they stated "This is the correct behaviour", although it happens only on 1 particular model (Air) and not on any other Macbook...

Answer (score 0):

Click and drag using two fingers on the trackpad.

In System Preferences > Trackpad, make sure Secondary Click is set to 'Click with two fingers'.

Comment: I've tried all key and gesture combinations I could think of, including those :\. Control+drag does regular drag and two-finger drag scrolls the view (zoom).

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea sounds like you are not clicking with your fingers. You need to put enough pressure to activate the mechanical "click" feeling in the trackpad.

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea you should turn off Tap to click in System Preferences > Trackpad to get rid of this behaviour, and also make the most of the macbook trackpad (pressing to click is better than tapping to click on macbooks).